# Populate Flow picklist values by calling external API

Tags: rest-api, visual-workflow, external-services

I am working on a pretty challenging problem. I need to do this mostly declaratively so I used Lighting Flow and External Services. I built a simple screen flow as shown below:

[image]

The issue is that I cant hardcode the picklist values like I did in the next picture:

[image]

This picklist choices is determined by calling an external API that takes Year as a paramter and then passes a list of cars as a response. The response looks like this:

```
{
  "Result": [
    "ACURA",
    "AIRSTREAM",
    "ALFA ROMEO",
    "ALLEGRA",
    "AMERICAN",
    "AUDI",
    "AUTOCAR",
    "BEAVER MOTOR COACH",
    "BLUEBIRD",
    "BMW",
    "BUICK",
    "CADILLAC",
    "CHEVROLET",
    "CHRYSLER",
    "COACHMEN",
    "COUNTRY COACH",
    "DAEWOO",.....
],
  "HasErrors": false,
  "Code": 200,
  "CorrelationId": "595ff16c9"
}
```

So if the response has this list of cars then the picklist needs to have those cars in the picklist. I went ahead created a Named credential and used External Service by pasting the JSON that I got from OpenAPI. But i cant figure out how I would create these picklist. Also, the year determines the list of cars. When you select a car that calls an API which determines the picklist values of the Model which then when you select a model determines the list of style by calling an API. Any guidance and help would be really appreciated. I am very stuck.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible with Flow? It should only be a few hours effort with some LWC and Apex, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is now easily possible after Winter 23 release feature ["Generate Flow Choice Options From External Data"](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_flow_choice_external_data.htm&type=5&release=240)

In order to use this feature, here is what you need to do,

1. First, create a data structure similar to your external data in Apex. Like for your use case, it will be like below

   ```
    public class ApexTypeCarResults {
      @AuraEnabled
      public List<String> Result;
      @AuraEnabled
      public Boolean HasErrors;
      @AuraEnabled
      public Integer Code;
      @AuraEnabled
      public String CorrelationId;
   }
   ```
2. In the next step, create a resource (Type variable) of Type Apex Defined and indicate this Apex class.
3. Make sure to populate the variable created in step 2 with the results from the external service via assignment.
4. Finally, when you use the out-of-box flow choice component, make sure to use the variable of the Apex-defined type you created in Step 2.